# Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$f(x) = x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$.  We can't use Eisenien Criterion since it won't apply to this particular $f(x)$ so i'm not really sure what else to do. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

By the rational roots theorem, this polynomial has no rational roots.  Therefore, if it is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it must factor into two quadratics with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Such a factorization, if it exists, is not hard to find.  Note that the polynomial **is** "quadratic" in $x^2$.

Therefore, you can apply the quadratic formula with the substitution $y = x^2$ and see if the resulting factorization it gives you has rational coefficients.  Applying this method, we get:

$$x^2 = \frac{10 \pm 4\sqrt{6}}{2} = 5 \pm 2\sqrt{6}$$

And so the factorization of the polynomial into two quadratics must be:

$$(x^2-(5+2\sqrt{6}))(x^2 + (5+2\sqrt{6}))$$

And so what can we conclude?

Comment: Since you showed it could factor into two quadratics, and you said "Therefore, if it is reducible over Q, then it must factor into two quadratics", then we conclude it is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is that right?

Comment: Well, I showed that it was possible to factor it into two quadratics, but the question is whether those quadratics are members of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  It's only reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if it factors into quadratics that have coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks! Reading over my textbook regarding this material makes more sense now.

Comment: How does it follow that the factorization into quadratics "must be" the one you wrote down? It's possible for a quartic to factor into quadratics over $\Bbb Q$ in one way, and upon rearrangement of roots to factor differently into a product of quadratics that are not over $\Bbb Q$ a different way. For instance $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ is a product of $(x-\sqrt{2})(x-\sqrt{3})$ and $(x+\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{3})$, neither of which is a polynomial over $\Bbb Q$. Doesn't mean $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ is irreducible.

Comment: I see your point @seaturtles.  From the above work, the linear factors will be $(x \pm \sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}})$ and $(x \pm \sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{6}})$, wich *is* a unique factorization since we are in a UFD.  From here, we can combine two linear factors however we choose, and from here we can see that no matter how a chosen linear factor multiplies with another linear factor, we will never get a quadratic in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: You would need to determine $\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\pm\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}$ are not both rational. While doing this in isolation for both sign choices would be difficult (sometimes complicated surds like this happen to simplify to rational numbers), one can argue by contradiction that they are not both rational.

Comment: @seaturtles In this case it's not too complicated since the the nested radicals simplify to $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ or one of its conjugates

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ has no odd powers of $x$, the only possible factorization into quadratics would have the form

$$(x^2+ax+\sigma)(x^2-ax+\sigma)$$

where $\sigma^2=1$ and $2\sigma-a^2=-10$.  But $\sigma^2=1$ implies $\sigma=\pm1$, which leads to $a^2=10\pm2$.  Since neither $12$ nor $8$ is a square, $f$ does not have any quadratic factors over the rationals.

The absence of odd powers and the fact that $f(0)\not=0$ now implies that $f$ has no *linear* factors either:  If $x-r$ were a factor, then $x+r$ would also be a factor, in which case $x^2-r^2$ would be a quadratic factor.  But we just proved that $f$ has no quadratic factors.